# List comprehension space removal in python

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension

I'm still getting my head around list comprehension in python, but I believe it's what I need for this task.

I have a string which I have cast to a list. I want to remove spaces if both adjacent elements are lowercase alphabet characters.

E.g

```
 INPUT> Bartho lemew The Rhinoceros
 OUTPUT> Bartholemew The Rhinoceros
```

Comment: you can just do a split on space on your string, which will put your sentence into a list without any spaces

Comment: Don't even try doing this with a list comprehension.

Comment: Where has the `'u'` come from in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) would be a better fit here:

```
import re

def remove_spaces(string):
    return re.sub(r'(?<=[a-z]) (?=[a-z])', '', string)

print(remove_spaces('Bartho lemew The Rhinoceros'))
# Bartholemew The Rhinoceros
```

Answer (score 0):

Very much similar to another answer

```
import re
a='Bartho lemew The Rhinoceros asdas'
print(re.sub('([A-Z][a-z]*)(\s)([a-z])(\w*)',r'\1\3\4',a))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think regular expressions are a little overhyped on stackoverflow for beginner questions. For this question though they're definitely the right choice. That said, you also asked for a list comprehension that solves the problem, and who am I to deny you?

```
def remove_spaces(s):
    s = s.join(['A', 'A'])
    return ''.join([c for i, c in enumerate(s)
                        if c!=' ' or not (s[i-1]+s[i+1]).islower()][1:-1])
```